# Visual Studio 2010 Intuit QBFC12 Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intuit-partner-platform

I am working on Quickbooks integration using web connector. I've installed QBSDK12 but but Visual Studio 2010 doesn't show any templates that I understand are supposed to be automatically installed with the SDK.

Is there something additional I need to do or install?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the \PROJECTTEMPLATESROOT directory.